# i want to increase string ID like "S1001" to "S1002" in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadb

[check image for information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkCXi.png)

im using netbeans javaDB.
when i press the new id button, i want to increase to "S1004" and show in text field
i want get last id from database
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

i want to increase string ID like “S1001” to “S1002”

This will work for your example

```
String id = "S1001";

String num = id.substring(1); // remove first char
int num = Integer.parseInt(num) + 1; // convert to int and increment

id = ("S" + num); // convert it back
```